# Best practices for streaming/batching of data

Tags: databricks

I'm routing data from my IoT Hub to a Data lake and I've played around with Databricks to process the data, but I'm not sure what is the best practice for receiving the data and have played around with two options:

##### Option #1 Streaming

The *spark.readStream* works great, but would it be cost efficient compared to batching in 1000 messages at the time?

##### Option #2 Streaming

Using Delta tables *COPY INTO* looked promising at first as it only fetches updated messages, but I cannot figure out how to continue promissing only the new rows. As if I query the Delta table I will get all the rows.

I could of course hold a global variable of when the batch was last processed or perhaps update the Delta table with a "processed" flag, but that doesn't seem right.

Thanks of the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ingestion of the similar data it's better to use streaming approach, so you will get only increments of the data.  But you don't need to run the pipeline all the time (higher costs) - you can setup a Databricks job that runs periodically (every hour/day/...) and configure stream to use `Trigger.Once` or `Trigger.AvailableNow` ([doc1](https://docs.databricks.com/structured-streaming/triggers.html#configuring-incremental-batch-processing), [doc2](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers)) that will make your pipeline behave like a batch, but work only with data increments.

On other side, COPY INTO is designed for incremental ingestion of file-based formats (CSV, JSON, ...) - it behaves similar to the streaming approach, just hiding a complexity. You just need to rerun it again & again pointing to the same landing zone - it will find only new files and ingest them.  You can find more information about this command in the [following blog post](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2023/01/17/easy-ingestion-lakehouse-copy.html).